# Combo Box with a sub query in it

Tags: ms-access, vba

So my boss wants me to add this sub query to a combo box which displays information from another query under it. I honestly have no idea how to do this.

Currently this is my code to populate the combo box

```
cmbGroups.RowSource = "Select GroupName, GroupNum from tblGroupHeader Where GroupName like '" & txtgroupSearch.Value & "*' or GroupNum like '" & txtgroupSearch.Value & "*';"
cmbGroups.Requery
cmbGroups.SetFocus
cmbGroups.Dropdown
```

Which in the form view looks like this.

[image]

I need to add another query, something like this:

```
"Select * from tblAlsoKnown where groupNum like '" & cmbGroups.Column(2) '";"
```

What it should do is ass all the alsoKnown groups under the appropriate group name which are linked by the group name. It's a one to many relationship so there can be many alsoknown groups for one single groupName.

So If I look at the image above the group "test1231" should have all the also known groups under it.

**a little bit of a premise**: *There are about 220 actual groups in my database. Each one has its own UNIQUE group number. Groups can change names often due to companies merging and absorbing other companies. A good example is how "Crysler" changed to "Daimler Chrysler". It's important that I log whose, whom. So I've crated a alsoKnown table that allows me to see companies previous name. Each single companie can have many alsoKnown names and they're all linked with the GroupNum.*

I'd like to know other programmers thoughts and opinions. Maybe best steps to take; really anything is helpful.

Comment: I'm about to head out. I'll look at this again Tuesday and see if anyone has responded!

Comment: I think I would first create an array storing values that you want to have in this dropdown and then populate the values into the combo box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is to just alter the SQL query that populates the combobox in that way that it fetches all the values you want. Like this:

```
"Select hea.GroupName, hea.GroupNum, kno.alsoKnownAs
FROM tblGroupHeader AS hea 
     INNER JOIN tblAlsoKnown AS kno 
                ON hea.groupNum = kno.groupNum 
WHERE hea.GroupName like '" & txtgroupSearch.Value & "*' OR
      hea.GroupNum like '" & txtgroupSearch.Value & "*' OR
      kno.GroupNum like '" & txtgroupSearch.Value & "*';"
```

You should group the values to your liking using the GROUP BY command.

Then you just populate the combobox like you already did.

My suggestion: Maybe you could add a third column "Also Known as" and put all the AlsoKnown values there? Of cource you need to alter the sql query then again.

Best regards

Comment: I like your suggestion with the 3rd column. How would I structure a query to insert values into a specific column?

Comment: Did you try the SQL query from my post? It should work as far as I know. I do not know your data model so I only assumed INNER JOIN would be the right way.
You also need to set the combobox properties to show three columns so it shows the last SELECT value kno.alsoKnownAs.

Comment: Yeah I gave it a shot, I don't need to search by also known by. I only need it to show them under the correct group.